# Draw the values of two variables each on a axis in a square

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, output-formatting

I plot lists of {xA1} over time and lists of {yB1} over time. Now, How can I draw two lists {xA1} and {yB1} so that the values of each are shown on a separate axis inside a square? (same as below image:)

[image: Please look at this Pic:]

Here is my  code:

```
a = 150; b = -150; c = -200; d = -500; e = 0; f = -300; g = 0; h =-100; dt = 0.001;

fun[XA1_, YB1_] := Block[{xA1, yB1, plot},
  (***List1:XA& XB***)
  xA1 = {XA1};
  xA2 = {1 - xA1[[1]]};
  yB1 = {YB1};
  yB2 = {1 - yB1[[1]]};
  (***List2:fitness of A***)
  UA1 = {(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f)*dt};
  UA2 = {(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h)*dt};
  (***List3:average fitness A***)
  UA = {(xA1[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*b + yB2[[1]]*f) + 
       xA2[[1]]*(yB1[[1]]*d + yB2[[1]]*h))*dt};
  (***List4:fitness of B***)
  UB1 = {(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c)*dt};
  UB2 = {(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g)*dt};
  (***List5:average fitness B***)
  UB = {(yB1[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*a + xA2[[1]]*c) + 
       yB2[[1]]*(xA1[[1]]*e + xA2[[1]]*g))*dt};
  (***Main Function***)
  For[t = 1, t < 100, t++,
   (***fitnesses A***)
   uA1 = yB1[[t]]*b + yB2[[t]]*f;
   uA2 = yB1[[t]]*d + yB2[[t]]*h;
   uA = xA1[[t]]*uA1 + xA2[[t]]*uA2;
   UA1 = Append[UA1, uA1*dt];
   UA2 = Append[UA2, uA2*dt];
   UA = Append[UA, uA*dt];
   (***fitnesses B***)
   uB1 = xA1[[t]]*a + xA2[[t]]*c;
   uB2 = xA1[[t]]*e + xA2[[t]]*g;
   uB = yB1[[t]]*uB1 + yB2[[t]]*uB2;
   UB1 = Append[UB1, uB1*dt];
   UB2 = Append[UB2, uB2*dt];
   UB = Append[UB, uB*dt];
   (***differential equations A***)
   xA1 = Append[xA1, xA1[[t]] + (xA1[[t]]*(uA1 - uA))*dt];
   xA2 = Append[xA2, xA2[[t]] + (xA2[[t]]*(uA2 - uA))*dt];
   (***differential equations B***)
   yB1 = Append[yB1, yB1[[t]] + (yB1[[t]]*(uB1 - uB))*dt];
   yB2 = Append[yB2, yB2[[t]] + (yB2[[t]]*(uB2 - uB))*dt];
   ];
  plot = ListLinePlot[{Labeled[xA1, "share of strategy A1 Palyer A"], 
     Labeled[yB1, "share of strategy B1 Palyer B"]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotRange -> 1, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False];
  Return[{xA1, yB1}];
  ];

A = Table[Table[fun[xA1, yB1], {xA1, 0, 1, 0.1}], {yB1, 0, 1, 0.1}];
```

Comment: Please post the code about `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks, I edite my question and add my code

Answer (score 1):

You may use "Overlay","Frame" and "FrameTicks" for this purpose.

Here is a simple example with only 2 curves:

```
pl1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}];
pl2 = Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, Pi}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{False, All}, {False, False}}];
Overlay[{pl1, pl2}]
```

[image]

However, if you want to draw {fun1[t],fun2[t]} with the parameter t you can use "ParametricPlot" like:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Exp[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but output of your code is not what I want.
Actually, the values of xA (that are in [0,1])  must be shown on 
horizontal axis and  values of yB (That are in[0,1])  must be shown on  vertical axis and both of them form a square pic ( Please see Pic that is in my question above)

Comment: Hope I understand you now right. I added a parametric plot.

Comment: I think that is what I want Daniel.I appreciate your help, Now, xA and yB are lists and ParametricPlot function plot points not Lines, how I can use something Like ParametricLinePlot to plot lines?

Comment: Use "Interpolation" to get functions from lists.